# How do I do a git pull to a specific branch?

Tags: git

I am trying to pull from my heroku remote, I get this message:

```
>git pull heroku
You asked to pull from the remote 'heroku', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
```

My local branch is 'develop'.

How do I pull from Heroku to my local branch 'develop' ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Updated answer: You need to specify what branch you want to pull from, since your local branch is not configured to pull from `heroku`'s `master`.

So try something like:

```
git pull heroku master
```

Remember that you have to have checked out `develop` in order for this command to pull to the local branch `develop`.

Comment: well my remote is called `heroku`. Remember I want my local branch you know....not the remote branch. when i do `git pull heroku develop`, I get a fatal error because there is no remote branch called develop. What I want to do is to pull from the remote master branch at the remote called `heroku`, to my local branch `develop`.

Comment: As the answer notes, master is the remote branch.

Answer (score 7):

Note: if you want to push/pull by default to `heroku/master` from your `develop` branch, you can configure it with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to develop heroku/master
```

You can check your merge policy on the `develop` branch with a:

```
git config branch.develop.merge
```

Note: As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509677/how-do-i-do-a-git-pull-to-a-specific-branch/5510047#comment86071158_5510047) by [Animay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897185/animay), since Git 1.8, [`--set-upstream` is renamed `--set-upstream-to`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575748/6309).
`--track` is also possible, [although slightly different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27076349/6309).

Comment: According to docs--"the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported. Please use '--track' or '--set-upstream-to' instead."

Comment: @Animay Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

When you pull you have to specify which remote branch you want to pull from. It doesn't make any sense to pull from just "heroku" because it may have multiple branches and Git doesn't know which one you want.

If there is only one branch on your remote then it's probably called "master". Try:

```
git checkout develop
git pull heroku master
```

This puts you into your local "develop" branch then pulls the "master" branch from the repository called "heroku".

Answer (score 4):

As of this writing, the command `git pull` provides the answer. When I try to `git pull` without any further arguments, it provided me the following information:

```
rockyinde.desktop% git pull
remote: Counting objects: 143, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (95/95), done.
remote: Total 143 (delta 75), reused 87 (delta 23)
Receiving objects: 100% (143/143), 29.59 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (75/75), completed with 33 local objects.
From ssh://git.rockyinde.com:<port>/code/myproject
   2d232ds..1hw1f84  frontline   -> rockyremote/frontline

There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

   git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

   git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> develop
```

So, all you need to be looking at (in the above output) is:

```
From ssh://git.rockyinde.com:<port>/code/myproject
   2d232ds..1hw1f84  frontline   -> rockyremote/frontline
```

which specifies your `remote`/`branch` information. And so, in my case it is:

```
git pull rockyremote frontline
```