# What's the difference between git "--track" and "--set-upstream-to"?

Tags: git

As I can see, both git `--track` and `--set-upstream-to` modify a branch so it becames a tracking (or upstream) branch. But where is a subtle difference I can't comprehend. The `--track` records "remote branch tracks local":

```
$ git checkout foo -b
$ git branch --track origin/retarget

Branch origin/retarget set up to track local branch foo.

$ cat .git/config
[branch "origin/retarget"]
        remote = .
        merge = refs/heads/foo
```

While `--set-upstream-to` records "local branch tracks remote branch":

```
$ git checkout foo -b
$ git branch --set-upstream-to origin/retarget

Branch foo set up to track remote branch retarget from origin.

$ cat .git/config
[branch "foo"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/retarget
```

What's the difference between this two? I was sure that "tracking branch" is simple concept with additional `upstream` pointer inside branch that tracks `head` position of specified branch in `remote` repository. But seems it's much more complicated?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$ git checkout foo -b
$ git branch --track origin/retarget
```

The first two commands instruct git to:

- create a local branch named "`origin/retarget`" (very bad idea, as it is named as a remote tracking branch", while it is actually a simple local branch with a '`/`' in its name)
- starting from the current branch ("`foo`", another local branch)
- to make that new local branch tracking its starting point.

See [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

```
--track
```

> When creating a new branch, set up `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` configuration entries to mark the start-point branch as "upstream" from the new branch.

You would use track when you create a branch starting from a remote tracking one.

In other word, your first example isn't how you would use `--track`.
This would work better:

```
git checkout -b foo --track origin/retarget
```

Or, using the more recent ([Git 2.23+, Q3 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)) [`git switch` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):

```
git switch -c foo --track origin/retarget
```

(there is no `--set-upstream-`to with `git switch`)

---

As for the difference between `--track` and `--set-upstream-to`:

```
--set-upstream-to
```

> If specified branch does not exist yet or if `--force` has been given, acts exactly like `--track`.
> Otherwise, sets up configuration like `--track` would when creating the branch, **except that where branch points to is not changed**.

---

Note that with [git 2.37 (Q2 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309), you can even forget about `--track` or `--set-upstream-to` with:

```
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
```

Then a `git push origin/retarget` would automatically link the current local and remote branch.

Answer (score 9):

Let's assume that you have one `master` branch which is checked out. Now when you do a

```
$ git branch --track someBranch
```

you will create a new branch named `someBranch` which changes will be tracked according to the `master` branch. But this branch has no remote branch set. Thus you see `remote = .` in the git config.

Now that `someBranch` is tracked it means that changes will appear in `git status` and `git branch -v` as if a remote exists.

For example if you make a commit on `someBranch` git will tell you that you are `1 ahead` when you do a `git branch -v` or when you do a `git status` it shows you

```
Your branch is ahead of 'master' by 1 commit.
```

And this is the interessting part. The branch is tracked and git shows you that it is 1 commit ahead of `master` (the branch that was checked out when you created `someBranch`)