# Cannot pull changes from master branch

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm working on a project with a friend and we each have separate branches, along with the master branch that hasn't been touched. I'm trying to merge my branch (called "dave") with the master branch. However, I get the following error:

```
Daves-MBP:project1 davesmith$ git pull master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Does anyone know what is going on here and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the branch you are, you would need at least:

```
git pull origin master:master
```

If [`master` tracks `origin/master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27076349/6309) (see `git branch -avv`), then this would be enough (since `pull` uses by default the remote repo named '`origin`')

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Note that doesn't merge `dave` to `master`, it only update or merge `origin/master` to `master`.

A merge would be:

```
git checkout master
git merge dave
```

But it is good practice indeed to first update `master` (to get the most up-to-date version from the remote repo), before merging another branch in the local (updated) `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to specify the repository.