# How to push a new branch non-existing on the remote server without --set-upstream?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

The scenario is that I have no repos on the remote server, just an account. Then, I run locally the following commands, where *x* is the user name and *y* is the project name that only exists on my local system.

```
git init  
git remote add buckety https://x@bitbucket.org/x/y.git  
git add .  
git commit --message "Here we go..."  
git push buckety
```

Now I get the error urging me to set up the remote upstream. I can do that (either *`--set-upstream`* or *`-u`*) but according to my googlearching, it's been deprecated. (Actually weird that the suggestion in the console mentions it still.)

I want to do it the proper way and I've goolearched both *`--track`* and *`--set-upstream-to`*. However, there's no example for my particular scenario on Git as far I could see and the operations I've tested failed with errors.

How should I create the remote branch without retracting to using the deprecated option? I might want to create a tracking branch on remote so that:

1. the local branch A corresponds to the remote branch A, but also
2. the local branch A corresponds to the remote branch B.

Preferably, I'd like to configure it **prior** to the push but I'm not sure how. I can't use *checkout* because the branch doesn't exist yet. I can't use *set-upstream-to* for the same reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The right command is:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Or, for more recent (2021+) repositories:

```
git push -u origin main
```

Then the next `git push` will be a simple: `git push`.

See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)"

[Since Git 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089415/6309), `--set-upstream` is called `--set-upstream-to`

[You can set up a remote tracking branch in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309) with:

```
git branch -u origin/master master
# or
git branch -u origin/main main
```

(Then your first `git push` would have been a simple `git push`)

Comment: So the *-u* **was** a short for *--set-upstream* before and now it's short for *--set-upstream-to*? Or should I understand that the deprecation isn't effective for the initial push (and that it's appropriate to use it) but that it's effective for subsequent work (and one shouldn't use it later on)? What exactly is the difference between *--set-upstream* and *--set-upstream-to* on the initial push? Nothing, right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten -u is still valid and now is indeed short for `--set-upstream-to`. `--set-upstream` is deprecated.

Comment: Awesome. But I'm a verbose person so I happen to use the *--set-upstream* withing the suffix. Revising the stuff on the server, I see no difference. What should I notice, please (if I wasn't so ignorant of the nuances)?

Comment: @KonradViltersten this is a local setting, for your local repo to know where to push (read http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309). You can see it when doing a `branch -vv master`

Comment: Godlike! I'd give you +1 but I already did because I got excited.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: the main difference between `--set-upstream` and `--set-upstream-to` lies in the *treatment of additional arguments*. Running `git branch newbr --set-upstream br2` *creates* branch `newbr` with its upstream set to `br2`; running `git branch oldbr --set-upstream-to br2` sets the upstream of *existing* branch `oldbr` to `br2`. The details get more fiddly when you're *not* creating a new branch and use `--set-upstream`.

Answer (score 2):

For me pushing an existing local branch to a branch that doesn't (yet) exist on the server is:

```
git push --set-upstream origin LocalBranchThatDoesntExistOnServer
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how i push to gerrit instance without adding remote

```
git push http://localhost:8080/scm *:*
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
```

But the project must exist already

Comment: Oh, I start to see the issue. I **must** create the repo by *git init* but executed **on the server**. Then, I can do the rest. Of course, BitBucket won't let me access the command line but I can create the repo from the GUI. I prefer to do stuff from TUIs. It always feels like GUI will make me lazy and dumb(er)... Also, working with text interface makes you look cool, like the kid from 80's movie *War Games*.

Comment: @KonradViltersten you would not be able to do a git init on the server side, since the server is BitBucket (bitbucket.org). You must have created an empty repo there (with the BitBucket web GUI) first.

Comment: I suggest you to follow this tutorial:

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/create-a-git-repository-759857290.html

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575748/492203), if you find that it's pushing to the wrong remote branch, e.g. after you've renamed the `master` branch to `main`, try this:

```
git push -u origin main:main
```